# Sending mail in WAMP

Tags: php, email, wamp

I'm trying to finish my contact form, but I can't send mail. I'm using the WAMP server.

I configured the php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
Port = 465
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = {myEmail}
```

My PHP file (just for testing) seems fine:

```
<?php
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: {myEmail}' . '\r\n';
mail("{myEmail}","test subject","test body",$headers);
?>
```

I try to send it by going to the send.php file but I get this error:

`SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for`
`Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.         x3sm881745yhd.9 in C:\wamp\www\send.php on line 5`

I have no clue what this means. I'm not really a PHP developer. I mainly work with JavaScript. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SSL for sending mail through gmail, and you cant do this with php, youll need a different smtp server